# Can adding a blog be an effective method for improving SEO?

Tags: seo, blog

It seems like these days everyone is preaching about adding a blog to your website to benefit your SEO, but just how effective is it? I know it will depend partly the on content etc. but with everyone starting up their own blog's all of a sudden, do they still have much impact and do they really help improve your SEO?

Comment: Who is preaching about this? I haven't seen anyone saying this for *years*. And all of a sudden? This myth has been around as long as blogs have.

Answer (score 10):

A blog can be beneficial to SEO, ***IF*** it contains quality content. Lets face it: Getting backlinks to a "boring" corporate website can be extremely difficult. I mean, who is going to link to your "About Me" section? Who is going to link to your website on the basis that they thought that your "Services" page was well written?

A blog can provide you with the platform to write about things that people will link to. i.e. Interesting articles that relate to your niche.

Comment: But this isn't because it's a blog. It's because it's quality content. The format is irrelevant.

Comment: Are there other platforms that would allow a local business website to generate quality content? I mean, an "About Me" section could contain quality content, but the likelihood of it being linked to is almost null. I think it is worth noting that a blog is the easiest method for a business-based website to generate **fresh** quality content.

Comment: Yes, it can. But what I'm saying is the blog format isn't what's key here. You can produce quality content without it being a blog.

Comment: I agree with you on that point. However, the question is "Is a blog really that effective for improving SEO?" The answer is: Yes, they can be, IF it is done correctly.

Comment: Certainly it is. Our site is rather dry and informational by necessity. It's quite formal and I wouldn't expect anyone to link to us, customer or not. But by adding a "blog" format, we can loosen up, focus on trending issues, even put in a little humor that we can tweet about. For me, it seems to be a tone issue. If your site's tone is appealing, no need to add a blog to generate backlinks. But if it necessitates dry content like ours does, consider adding some character elsewhere.

Comment: And the quality content has to be published on a consistent basis. Google likes fresh, new content daily.

Answer (score 6):

Blogs, in-and-of themselves, have no SEO benefits inherit to them. Just having a blog on your site does not offer any SEO benefit and the blog format offers no inherit value either. This myth started when WordPress sites were becoming popular and were ranking well. But this was due to the  code being well optimized and the content being good. It had was *not* because they were blogs.

Comment: The idea that has always been suggested was the more pages the better, but obviously having the content counts as well.

Comment: That is definitely *not* true.

Comment: Might be worthy to note that though this way the blog might not contribute, people might continue to browse your site after the blogitem, which could have a possitive efect

Comment: Blogs have a lot of features that make content creation through them easier and automatically search engine friendly. There are other ways to achieve that, but a blog is often a good choice.

Answer (score 5):

I would say a blog help you mainly to earn new clients because you can get some traffic from search engines for the long tail (more keywords than your actual ones). A blog helps you to make a good and large reputation for your business in a field you know well. With a good blog, you can create or participate to a community about your field of expertise.

For SEO, it also helps because your site grows up (a new page for each new article). Moreover, your site is considered by Google with "fresh" content (if you often add some good articles with original content). This last point is important for SEO and when you have a site where you can't add new pages easily, a blog is a good solution. Moreover, indirectly, your readers can like your original content and share it by creating backlinks to your articles.

Answer (score 4):

Should you regularly post articles in your subject area that users would find helpful?  **Yes, absolutely**.

Does it have to be a blog?  **Not necessarily**, but a blog can be a good choice for doing so:

- Blogs are generally ordered by published date (newest first) which encourages you to keep them updated.
- Because blog posts fall off the front page eventually, it doesn't hurt to write about something and see if it gains traction.  A blog is usually seen as a less formal setting than your main website and can be a great place to experiment.
- You can post to a blog from a web interface.  Once it is set up, you don't need to get a server administrator involved to push new content live.
- Blog software generally has decent SEO up front.  Blogs can start getting traffic from search engines within a couple weeks of publishing a few posts.

If you already have quality content available to search engine bots on your main website and are adding to it regularly, a blog probably won't do anything for your SEO that you are not already doing.

If you currently have a five page website and it is harder to write content for your current website than it would be to write blog posts, then a blog can really ease that friction and get you rolling on content creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you write answers to questions your customers are searching for then yes. Just remember to add a direct link (with a price and picture) to your article so you actually get conversions, not just seo.

If you write about random stuff that is just filled with random keywords then no.

[Have a look at what Matt Cutts (who responsible for the search department in Google) says about blogs.](https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp/search?query=blog)